# Let $I$ be a proper ideal of a commutative ring. Prove that $I$ is a radical ideal if and only if the ring $R/I$ has no zero nilpotent elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a proper ideal of a commutative ring. Prove that $I$ is a radical ideal if and only if the ring $R/I$ has no zero nilpotent elements.

My attempt for one direction:

Suppose $R/I$ has a nonzero nilpotent element, $\{r+a: a \in I\}$ then $(r+a)^m=0$ for all $a\in I$. Because $a$ is equivalent to 0, we have $r^m=0$. This means $r^m \in I$, so $r^m \in \sqrt{I}$. From this we know $r^{mn}\in I$ for some $n>0$. Here I am stuck. I am trying to arrive at the contradiction that $r + a$ is 0. To do that I need to show that $r$ is 0, but I am struggling to do this.

Comment: Hi: don't hide the question in the title. It's perfectly fine if it appears in both the body and the title.  I've done this for you this time but in the future remember it'll make your post better.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means $r^m \in I$, so $r^m \in \sqrt{I}$.  From this we know $r^{mn}\in I$

No, do it in the other order. If $r^m\in I$, then  $r\in \sqrt{I}$, as $\sqrt{I}:=\{x\mid x^n\in I \text{ for some } n\in \mathbb N\}$.

Then since $\sqrt{I}=I$, you have $r\in I$, so that $r+I=0+I$ is the zero element, and you're done.

One tip: don't try thinking of cosets as sets like this: "$\{r+a: a \in I\}$ then $(r+a)^m=0$". It can lead to mistakes. The coset $r+I$ is an element, and $(r+I)^n:=r^n+I$ and you should not have to refer to the contents of $I$ at any point when doing arithmetic with them. What you wrote would be best written as

$r^m+I=0+I\implies r^m\in I$

Comment: Thank you. This makes complete sense.